# How to send auto email for new unapproved comments?

Tags: 8, emails, comments

How do I config to send auto email for new unapproved comments.

I enabled the comments module and anonymous user can create comments in some content types.

But, I want to receive in an specific email acount a notification for each new comment.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### using [simple_comment_email_notification](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_comment_email_notification)

and will send email notification to the site email configured at `admin/config/system/site-information` without any configuration

### using rules

[Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module allows you  to 
**Add reaction rule** by going to `admin/config/workflow/rules/reactions/add`

> React on event > After saving new comment

And add action

> system > send email

**NOTE:** rules is still in alpha stage at this time so some things might not work as expected if at all (above procedure has not been tested)